# Sum of all integers between two integers

Tags: python, math, range

I am using Python and I want to find the sum of the integers between 2 numbers:

```
number1 = 2
number2 = 6
ans = (?)
print ans

#the numbers in between are 3,4,5
```

Please give me either the mathematical formula or the Python code to do this.

Comment: use `sum` and `range`

Comment: Please make an effort before asking us to "give you code" or an analytical formula.

Comment: hint: google for arithmetic series.

Comment: mathematically you can use sum of AP: `(n/2)*(first+last)`. In your case : (3/2)*(3+5).

Comment: it works but

    num1 = 2
    num2 = 4

 i expect 3 but i get [2, 3]

Comment: See Carl Friedrich Gauss

Comment: Take a shot at providing pseudocode for what you want to do.  Something like: 1) define a variable total, and set to zero; 2) for each number between number1 and number2, add the current number to the total; 3) print the total.  Once you get the logic right, you can write the Python statements to do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

Given two numbers A and B (both inclusive) where B > A, the sum of values between A & B is given by

```
B(B + 1)/2 - (A - 1)A/2
=(B^2 + B - A^2 + A)/2
=((B - A)(B + A) + (B + A))/2
=(B + A)(B - A + 1)/2
```

If A & B are both exclusive, then replace B with B - 1 and A with A + 1. The rest I leave it for you as an exercise

Read through the [Python Expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) to translate the mathematical expression to Python Code

**Note**
Unfortunately, SO does not support MathJax or else the above expression could had been formatted better

Comment: Note the expected output from the user's code?

Comment: Now i need to add together all numbers in a list

Comment: num1 = 2
        num2 = 5
        [2, 3, 4]
        9

Comment: @pydsigner: So how my explanation deviates from what OP wants?

Comment: I read the comment, and came to the wrong conclusion. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You need this to get the sum:

```
ans = number1  + number2
```

Or is this not what you wanted to do?
Since you commented: `the numbers in between are 3,4,5`, do you mean this?

```
>>> for i in range(number1+1,number2):
...     print i
... 
3
4
5
```

**EDIT:**
So, OP also needs sum of all numbers between two numbers:

```
>>> number1 = 2
>>> number2 = 6
>>> sum(range(number1 + 1, number2))
12
```

This second part given by OP.

Comment: No problem, you might want to look at the other answer and redo it again, though ;)

Comment: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/31572/

Comment: @user2140889 good so you have done.

Comment: @pydsigner did you notice? as OP posted link, I was near to the answer. ;)

Comment: Yes, I looked at that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I like Grijesh's answer, simple and elegant. Here is another take on it, using a recursive call:

```
global sum
def sum_between(a, b):
    global sum
    # base case
    if (a + 1) == b:
        return sum
    else:
        sum += (a + 1)
        return sum_between(a + 1, b)
```

Not as straight forward as using sum(range(a+1, b)). But simply interesting as an exercise in recursive functions.

Comment: If it's recursive, why do you need to use a global variable?

Comment: good point, thank you for that Makoto.