# Not sure what type of loop to use in this java assignment

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, pseudocode

The assignment is to write a program for this
"Input 2 integers and add up all the numbers between them. If there is no room betwen them, output a 0."

I'm still very new to loops and I understand while loops so I want to use one. I'm not sure I understand how a for loop works mechanically and if it would be a better fit here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you can use any type of loop you want. although a `for` loop would be the ideal option.

Comment: Ok, I'll figure out how to make a for loop work if it's my best bet. I'm going to have to become familiar with them eventually...

Comment: if you haven't learnt for loops yet then use a `while` loop, there's no issue with it. it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: You don't need a loop. There's a closed form [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591547/sum-of-all-integers-between-two-integers) for this. Just be careful with overflow.

Comment: This is for school and my professor is pretty adamant about us not using utilities we haven't been taught yet. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This question is designed to be answered with a for loop.

Review: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

You want to concentrate on the correct expressions for the "initialization" and "termination" parts of the loop.

eg, in:

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

You want to find the values to replace `1` and `11`, and of course replace the `System.out.println` with what it should be.

Beyond that, I'm not going to do your homework for you.  Good luck!  I hope that you enjoy learning.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I like doing the work, just looking for some guidance to learn the right way.

Comment: I have a question. If I'm supposed to add all the values together that are in between the two user decided integers. How do I store those values? I think I would sum = value1 + value2 + etc but how can I initialize enough variables to know how many will be inside of the gap? I'm doing research on arrays (thanks to your link) and think thats the right road to go down. Can I command the system to add all arrays or variables found during the loop together to create a the sum value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any type of loops but `for loop` will make it easy for you
.. take a look at this example

```
int a=5;
int b=10;
int sum=0;
if((b-a)>1){
    for(int i=a+1;i<b;i++){
        sum=sum+i;
    }        
}
System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
```

Comment: This is a REALLY helpful template. I think I'll try to write down the steps you took on loose leaf so I can understand why it should look like this. Thank you.