# How to make a function that adds all whole numbers within a range of two numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, range, addition

Say I have two integers, a low and a high that I want to use as inputs to a function that adds all whole numbers between the range. I know I'm supposed to use a for range loop but I'm having trouble getting this. How would you write a function that does this? Thanks!

edit: Yeah, I keep playing with it and am not getting what I'm looking for. For example with the inputs, 3, 7 I'm trying to get a result of 25, but unfortunately am getting 18

```
def sum_vals(num1, num2):
    result = sum(range(num1, num2))
    print(result)

sum_vals(3, 7)
```

Comment: That's a one-liner, man. You definitely can do this yourself easily, just give it a try!

Comment: `help(range)` and `help(sum)` should be all you need here.

Comment: if you like it more mathematically: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842152/finding-the-sum-of-numbers-between-any-two-given-numbers  there is a formula to do it...

Comment: Dupe;:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591547/sum-of-all-integers-between-two-integers

Comment: Yeah, I keep playing with it and am not getting what I'm looking for. FOr example with the inputs, 3, 7 I'm trying to get a result of 25, but unfortunately am getting 18

Comment: You range is going from 3 till 6, you need :result =sum(range(num1,num2+1))

Answer (score 2):

The `result` should be calulated like this:

```
result = sum(range(num1,num2+1))
```